# Logout from all services in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor-webassembly, clean-architecture

I have three services that use separate clients (Blazor WebAssembly) and servers (ASP.NET Core). Additionally, I have an Identity service that all my other services use for Authentication and Authorization.

Here's the question:
When a user clicks the Logout button on the client side of the Identity service, I need to ensure that the user is also logged out from the other services.  How can I implement it? Handling it for a single service is straightforward, in identity service logout I can simply call:

`navigationManager.NavigateTo("https://otherservice/logout")`

and then clean the local storage. Since I have more than one service I don't know how to implement it.

I was thinking about using logout endpoints as a chain, for example:
on identity clients logout i will call my first services logout. On first services logout endpoint I call the second services logout endpoint and so on.

Also, while googling I find out about Web Pub/Sub. But turns out to implement it I need some subscription on aws or azure.

Answer (score 0):

If you use one domain and many subdomains. When cleaning localstorage data you will clean that for all your applications-subdomains(I think).